# I need to fill the remaining array with values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am in a bit tricky situation and I cannot seem to find any solution.
I have two objects in an array, the rest is empty.

As soon as I try to do something with the empty ones, I get the "undefined" error, thus the line `typeof place_position === 'undefined'`
I want to replace the empty ones with the text "empty", but it ends with the whole array having the values "empty" in every slot. This is the code snippet I am using:

```
for(var i = 0; i < pathsArray.length; i++){
        for(var b = 0; b < 2; b++){
                if(typeof place_position === 'undefined'){
                pathsArray[i].push("empty");
        }else{
                pathsArray[i].push(data.paths[i].places[b].place_position);
            }
    }       
}
```

Much help appreciated!

Comment: `{1,2}`, `{1,3}` are not objects in Javascript. Your example does not make sense.

Comment: `{1,2}` will give you a syntax error.

Comment: you also cannot push to an object

Comment: It's just an example. The objects aren't actually {1,2}. Removed it for clarification. Anyway, I want to push values into the rest of the array.

Comment: Use the array.fill() method https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill You might have to include the provided polyfill for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN example](https://jsbin.com/caneso/13/edit?js,console)

```
var newArray = pathsArray.concat(Array(4).fill('empty'));
```

Comment: I think I'm extremely bad at explaining:

It was stupid of me to include {}. There's nothing there.

Comment: My keyboard is weird, sorry. The thing is that I only have two objects in an array. There is nothing else. Theres 1:2, and 1:3 in the array. I want to add more through .push(), however, with the value "empty". It has worked to push things into this array before.

Comment: Four of these values. So it would be [{1:2}, {1:3}, "empty","empty", "empty", "empty"] I think.

Comment: Thing is that I would like it to do it through pathsArray.length, if I set the array-length to 6. Is that possible?

Comment: Final try...there you go